# how to properly specify image anchor with Jade

Tags: pug

I'm using someone else's Node app sample, which uses Jade templating (which I do not know at all).
I have this line, which displays a regular hyperlink to log in with facebook:

```
a(href="/auth/facebook") Login via Facebook
```

I have a facebook.jpg image, which I would like to use instead of a plain hyperlink.

What is the proper Jade syntax to use this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to nest the `a` inside an `img`, just like you would in plain HTML. Although in Jade nesting is done in one of two ways:

With [indents](http://jade-lang.com/reference/tags):

```
a(href="/auth/facebook")
    img(src='facebook.jpg')
    | Login via Facebook
```

<sup>([`|` for plaintext](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text))</sup>

Or with `#[]` for a one-liner:

```
a(href="/auth/facebook") #[img(src='facebook.jpg')] Login via Facebook
```

---

Also, you can always just use plain HTML and it would work.